# SharePoint Online - Accept Terms Before Use

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was asked by a client today about implementing a page on their SharePoint site to accept their terms of use before users are able to access the site.

These terms would then need to be accepted every year as a reminder.

Would this be relatively simple to do? I'm a .NET webdev by day but have never touched SharePoint, or Sharepoint Online and everything I come across  online appears to be outdated. Ideally I'd like to use something in the backend to track whether these terms have been accepted but happy to use a cookie if necessary.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Thanks